# Threejs 2D Texture array issue when read raw image data

Tags: javascript, three.js, binaryfiles

When I Try To execute this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl2_materials_texture2darray), I see its work fine with current [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352270/Getting-started-with-Volume-Rendering), But when I try to put my binary file which is contain continuous 2D frames jpg image was exported from [here](https://www.dicomlibrary.com/meddream/md5/index.html?study=1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.1055.1.20111102150758591.92402465.76095170) I got a none detailed image like this:

[image]

And this is converter binary code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=head256x256x1092.bin');

$dirs = scandir('512');
unset($dirs[0]);
unset($dirs[1]);
natsort($dirs);
foreach($dirs as $dir):
$fp = fopen('512/'.$dir, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
}
fclose($fp);

endforeach;
?>
~
```

And this is threejs file reader:

```
new THREE.FileLoader()
      .setResponseType( 'arraybuffer' )
      .load( 'head256x256x1092.zip', function ( data ) {

        var zip = new JSZip( data );
        var array = zip.files[ 'head256x256x1092.bin' ].asUint8Array();

        var texture = new THREE.DataTexture2DArray( array, 256, 256, 109 );
        texture.format = THREE.RedFormat;
        texture.type = THREE.UnsignedByteType;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
          uniforms: {
            diffuse: { value: texture },
            depth: { value: 0 },
            size: { value: new THREE.Vector2( planeWidth, planeHeight ) }
          },
          vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vs' ).textContent.trim(),
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs' ).textContent.trim()
        } );
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( planeWidth, planeHeight );
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );
      } );
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTexture are arrays of rgb
jpeg files are compressed data, it's not the same.
You can use this function:

```
function jpegToBinaryData( $filename ) {
  $data = '';
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $filename );
  for( $y = 0; $y < imagesy( $img ); $y++ ) {
    for( $x = 0; $x < imagesx( $img ); $x++ ) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat( $img, $x, $y );
        $r = ( $rgb >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
        $g = ( $rgb >> 8 ) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        $data .= chr( $r ) . chr( $g ) . chr( $b );
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I cant accept this solution since I cant tested it now, I change behavior, so that I vote up your answer now :D, (if I see more votes in answer, I will be happy to accept it sure)